# How to get temperature of the linux and reboot if needed

Tags: shell

I need a shell script which can reboot my PC if GPU temperature goes under 40 celsius. anyone can help?

I already tried this

```
     for line in $(cat log.txt);do
echo $line 
done
```

but i dont know how to make a check list loop and make it reboot if the value become under 40C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I could see *over* 40C. Why under 40C?

Comment: under because if its stop working

Comment: Your PC does not stop working when the CPU gets too **cool**.

Comment: Its 100% usage all time if gets cool its something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following reboots the PC if the temperature of the `Core 0` CPU rises above 99:

```
/usr/bin/sensors | awk '/Core 0/{if ($3+0 > 99) print}' | grep -q . && sudo reboot
```

If really want to reboot when the temperature drops below 40, then replace `> 99` with `< 40`.

Comment: @UlissesSilva What software do you have installed that can show GPU temperatures?  Is `/usr/bin/sensors` installed and, on your system, does it show GPU temperatures?

Comment: sudo apt-get install nvclock